# React/react-router: Is it possible to integrate non-react pages into react web app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to reactJS and am developing a web app. This is a general question so general guidance/advice will be appreciated.

1. Can I integrate non-react pages (i.e. pure HTML and Javascript pages) into react web app? Creating non-critical and more or less static pages in react seems like too much work for me.
2. If so, how do I handle routes to non-react pages in react-router-dom? Or do I need separate routing logic in the backend for this? I was wondering if it can be done like following:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
   import Home from "./routes/Home";
   import Post from "./routes/Post";
   import Profile from "./routes/Profile";
   /*
   import non-react pages here.?
   */

   function App() {
     return (
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
         <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
         <Route path="/r/:postid" exact={true} component={Post}/>
         <Route path="/:username" exact={true} component={Profile}/>
          /*
           Route non-react pages here?
          */
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
     );
   }

   export default App;
   ```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you need `route` to switch different part of frontend pages which has no relationship with react, the `micro-service` maybe a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a redirect element inside de route:

```
<Route path="/pricing">
   <Redirect to="www.something.com" ></Redirect>
</Route>
```